# Authorization Issue with Certbot(Standalone)+Nginx+Chef

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, lets-encrypt, certbot

I use Nginx on my server and want to serve my application on HTTPS using Let's Encrypt certs. I do the following on a fresh server before the application code gets deployed:

- Install Nginx
- Write the following `nginx` configuration file to `sites-available`, for certbot. Then symlink to `sites-enabled` and restart `nginx`

  ```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name foo.bar.com;
    allow all;

    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
      proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:22000;
   }
  }
  ```
- Then run `certbot`

  ```
  certbot certonly -m foo@bar.com --standalone --http-01-port 22000 --preferred-challenges http --cert-name bar.com -d foo.bar.com --agree-tos --non-interactive
  ```

All of the above work fine when run manually.

I use Chef to automate the above process. Certbot gets a 404 the first time I deploy. It works on subsequent deployments though.

Keep a note of the following detail:

- The phenomenon happens only when I freshly install Nginx and then run my deploy script through Chef and disappears on subsequent deploys.
- I use a custom LWRP to run the above steps in Chef expcept nginx installation. Nginx installation is taken care of by `chef_nginx`. I've pasted the snippet of the LWRP that runs the above steps.

  ```
  vhost_file = "#{node['certbot']['sites_configuration_path']}/#{node['certbot']['sites_configuration_file']}"
  template vhost_file do
    cookbook 'certbot'
    source 'nginx-letsencrypt.vhost.conf.erb'
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    variables(
      server_names:   new_resource.sans,
      certbot_port:   node['certbot']['standalone_port'],
      mode:           node['certbot']['standalone_mode']
    )
    mode 00644
    only_if "test -d #{node['certbot']['sites_configuration_path']}"
  end

  nginx_site node['certbot']['sites_configuration_file']
  ```
- Using `certbot` in `standalone` mode on port `22000`

How do I make things work even on the first deployment ?

Comment: Is it possible that your chef deployment is executing tasks in that order : nginx configuration -> certbot exec -> nginx reload ? In that case, nginx wouldn't know how to handle the certbot request on the first run.

Comment: I checked the logs. The order seems fine. I also used `watch` to monitor `nginx` workers in the process list.